# Additional serires label in highcharts columnrange

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have an inverted columnrange chart in highcharts. I am able to create a unique label for the low and high point for each range.

But as the chart gets longer I would like to label each on the columns by their series name.

I need a third label? Possibly something above each range that would display the name of the series. So far, I'm using the formatter to give each point a unique label.

```
plotOptions: {
  columnrange: {
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      formatter: function() {
        if (this.y === this.point.low) {
          return 'low: ' + this.y;
        }
        if (this.y === this.point.high) {
          return 'high: ' + this.y;
        }
        return 'blah';
      }
    }
  }
},
```

My fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zeus6ky9/6/

Comment: can you provide an illustration of how it look?

Comment: just need to place text above each of the horizontal bars.

Comment: There may be a number of ways, including either the *label* or the *renderer*, but I would personally approach this by using a scatter series, with invisible markers, making use of that series' data label.

Comment: I ended up using another column range series with the same data points and kept it hidden. Then I was able to display the label inside that range so it would line up visually with the other series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up adding an additional invisible series for each series already there. And creating a label for it.